# WSDL file schema location can not be found

Tags: java, web-services, spring, wsdl

While trying to use soapUI I get the error message saying it fails to load the schema request.xsd
here is how my wsdl looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
              xmlns:schema="http://www.myweb/xml/webservice"
              xmlns:tns="http://www.myweb.com/xml/webservice"
              targetNamespace="http://www.myweb.com/xml/webservice">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.myweb.com/xml/webservice"                      
            schemaLocation="/WEB-INF/schemas/Request.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
```

and here is how my spring config file is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="payloadMapping"   class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">
    <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="inferenceEndPoint" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref local="validatingInterceptor" />
            <ref local="payLoadInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="payLoadInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor" />

<bean id="validatingInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
    <description>
        This interceptor validates the incoming
        message contents
        according to the 'Request.xsd' XML
        Schema file.
    </description>
    <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/schemas/Request.xsd" />
    <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
    <property name="validateResponse" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="mwsid" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
   <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/spring-ws.wsdl"/>
</bean>

<bean id="inferenceEndPoint" class="com.mywebsite.ws.web.InferenceEndPoint">
    <property name="messageService" ref="messageService" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageService" class="com.mywebsite.ws.service.MessageService">
    <property name="inferenceService" ref="inferenceService" />
</bean>

<bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/schemas/Request.xsd" />
</bean>


<bean id="inferenceService" class="com.mywebsite.ws.im.InferenceService">
    <property name="webServiceConfiguration" ref="playerConfiguration" />
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="inferenceConfig" class="com.mywebsite.ws.im.InferenceService"> 
    <constructor-arg ref="playerConfiguration"/> </bean> -->

<!-- ~~~~~~~ Application beans ~~~~~~~ -->
<bean id="playerConfiguration"
    class="com.mywebsite.ws.configuration.WebServiceConfiguration"
    init-method="init">
    <property name="playerConfigXml" value="/WEB-INF/config/webserviceconfiguration.xml" />
    <property name="executingPathResource" value="/WEB-INF" />
    <property name="developmentMode" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Which spring-ws jar(s) do you have exactly?

Comment: spring-ws-1.5.9-all.jar  and spring-ws-1.5.9-sources.jar

Comment: Then that's the problem: http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd => download http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/release/SWS/spring-ws-2.0.2.RELEASE-full.zip

Comment: ok..now I ahve the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet  also how will I use the .xsd file that I have downloaded?

Comment: no no no. don't download the xsd. download the zip: http://s3.amazonaws.com/dist.springframework.org/release/SWS/spring-ws-2.0.2.RELEASE-full.zip, unzip it to your lib.

Comment: ok, In eclipse I added only those 2 jar files to my buildpath (spring-ws-all and spring-ws-sources) but I got those error, do I have to add all the jars in the zip? I tried also directly adding the zip to my buildpath, than I got more errors. tnx!

Comment: Now I managed to compile new jars without error, but still have same two problems 1-soapUI cant find request.xsd and 2-if I want to add this code : <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="MyWSService"
    portTypeName="MyWSPort"
    locationUri="http://localhost:8080/mws/">
   <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schemas/Request.xsd" />
   </sws:dynamic-wsdl>   still cant create a new wsdl, but yes now I do not get errors, only a warning about it.

Comment: About request.xsd, follow McDowell's advice. Regarding the warning, the best would be to create another question with the exact warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're creating a new soapUI project by picking the WSDL off the local disk. The tool is reading the file and baulks when it gets to `/WEB-INF/schemas/Request.xsd` as this path tells it to go to the root directory and look for a directory called `WEB-INF`. It would also be wise to ensure consistency when discussing case (the file says `Request.xsd` but your problem statement says `request.xsd`; this matters on some platforms.

Change the import in the WSDL to:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.myweb.com/xml/webservice"                      
        schemaLocation="schemas/Request.xsd"/>
```

This assumes the XSD is in the schemas directory relative to the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your configuration files and state the schema location in full path.

Comment: what you mean by "edit files"? I know I have to edit something but dont know how is that..